# I keep getting an error when writing not-found.js in Next13 (app router)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, hot-reload, turbopack

I wrote not-found.tsx on top of the default file created when create next app. It seems to be working fine, but the console keeps giving me an error every second.

Also, when I run the next app with next dev --turbo, a huge error occurs when accessing localhost:3000/404.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am now new to next.js. And I am learning App Router. The question that comes to mind while learning is whether this can be applied to a product. I feel like Next.js is too shabby, and as someone who developed only React as a SPA for 4 years, it's very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a catch-all route where the 404 was being generated from to return notFound() from it.

Create a folder: e.g. [...404]
Create a page.tsx or page.jsx page with the following:

```
import { notFound } from "next/navigation"
export default function NotFound() {
  return notFound()
}
```

Full article
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/40000

Comment: I'm really sorry, but none of the answers in the link https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/40000 work properly in Next13.4.19 on Turbopack